# How to prevent non-proficient internet users from scrolling past a hero carousel?

Tags: carousel

If the biggest part of your clients are people who lack internet skills how do you prevent them from ignoring your hero if its a carousel?

I'm not even sure if that would be the best approach. Should you approach this problem in a completely different way?

Comment: http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/

Comment: Then why so many people keep using carousels? Basically every designer on Behance/Dribbble uses them on their designs.

Comment: Because designers aren't focused on User Experience, they're focused on design. They likely haven't come across the unfortunate realization that you have which is that users often overlook carousels, because they aren't responsible for testing their designs past how it looks.

Comment: And because a lot of marketing departments influence web design, with very little understanding of ux.

Comment: lol at @KenMohnkern and DasBeasto. And it's even funnier because it's so true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All user types (proficient and non-proficient) will scroll past your carousel. People don't watch carousels; they start right away looking for information that will help them accomplish the task they came to the site with. ([This article by Nielsen/Norman](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/designing-effective-carousels/) describes the problem and provides some things to consider.)

I think the only realistic answer to your actual question is to make your page unscrollable. But then you'll be dealing with users abandoning your site, rather than just scrolling away from the carousel.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer.... Make your page the carousel.  Take whatever is in the carousel and make it page content that the user can scroll through.

Either way, like others have said, there is no way to force a user to watch a carousel without locking the scroll until the carousel has played through at least once.

Comment: I was thinking maybe there is a technique to focus user's attention to the carousel. I thought that because everyone seems to use carousels and I heard they are bad so I was like "hm, they probably know something I don't". Apparently I was wrong and the best way is to not use the carousel at all.

Comment: @LucianoInfanti, I'll play devil's advocate and tell you that in fact, there are certain techniques anchored in behavioral psychology. But this will require a lot of resources for something that in fact, means very little. For example: Apple's site uses carousels, and talking with one of their UX guys about NNG's article he told me: *"our research shows it works for us. But we devote an entire team only for that page and its testing"*. So... unless you can devote Apple resources.... better avoid them